# Linq To SQL InsertAllOnSubmit and DeleteAllOnSubmit

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Can I revert deleted objects from `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` by calling `InsertAllOnSubmit()` again,
or the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the original values by calling:

```
GetOriginalEntityState()
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.getoriginalentitystate)